# how to repeat the rows for the key of key value

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I received the json data in AngularJs and want to display the particular value of json data in table using ng-repeat.

json data:

```
{  
   "15":{  
      "Unique number":"133077",
      "Designation":"Software Engineer",
   },

   "16":{  
      "Unique number":"133079",
      "Designation":"Senior Software Engineer",
   },

   "18":{  
      "Unique number":"143688",
      "Designation":"Senior Software Engineer",
   }

}
```

I want to display in table like this using HTML:

| uniq no   |   designation              |

| 133077      | Software Engineer        |

| 133079      | Senior Software Engineer |

| 143688      | Senior Software Engineer |

Any help please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should do the AngularJS Tutorial on Code School. The tutorial should help you with this https://www.codeschool.com/pages/angularjs-vs-angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.members = {  
   "15":{  
      "Unique number":"133077",
      "Designation":"Software Engineer",
   },

   "16":{  
      "Unique number":"133079",
      "Designation":"Senior Software Engineer",
   },

   "18":{  
      "Unique number":"143688",
      "Designation":"Senior Software Engineer",
   }

}; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <table>
  <thead>
    <th>SI.NO</th>
    <th>Unique number</th>
    <th>Designation</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
      <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
      <td>{{member['Unique number']}}</td>
      <td>{{member.Designation}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to add another column as SI.No. 
Here the SI.No has to be generated as the rows get created. 
expecting output:
SI.NO | uniq no | designation |

1        | 133077 | Software Engineer |

2        | 133079 | Senior Software Engineer |

3        | 143688 | Senior Software Engineer |.

Comment: @siddharth updated my answer. please upvote if its the solution u are looking for

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** OP changed the requirement to add an extra field to display serial number.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {"15":{
"Unique number":"133077", "Designation":"Software Engineer", }, 
"16":{
"Unique number":"133079", "Designation":"Senior Software Engineer", }, 
"18":{
"Unique number":"143688", "Designation":"Senior Software Engineer", }
};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>Sl. No.</th>
    <th>Unique number</th>
    <th>Designation</th>
  </thead>
  <tr ng-repeat='(key, value) in data'>
    <td>
      {{$index + 1}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{value["Unique number"]}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{value["Designation"]}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution base on new components architecture simple for understand:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  // app.js
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .component('myApp', {
      template: '<items-table items="$ctrl.items"></items-table>',
      bindings: {},
      controller: function() {
        this.items = {
          "15": {
            "Designation": "Software Engineer",
            "Unique number": "133077"
          },
          "16": {
            "Designation": "Senior Software Engineer",
            "Unique number": "133079"
          },
          "18": {
            "Designation": "Senior Software Engineer",
            "Unique number": "143688"
          }
        };
      }
    });

  const itemsTableTemplate = `
<div class="items">
  <h2>Items</h2>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>unique no</th>
        <th>designation</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="(id, item) in $ctrl.items track by id">
        <td ng-bind="item['Unique number']"></td>
        <td ng-bind="item['Designation']"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
`;

  // items-table.component.js
  angular
    .module('app')
    .component('itemsTable', {
      template: itemsTableTemplate,
      bindings: {
        items: '<'
      },
      controller: ItemsTableController,
      controllerAs: '$ctrl'
    });

  function ItemsTableController() {
    // Constructor
  }
  
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app'), ['app'], {
    strictDi: true
  })
  
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-app>
    Loading...
  </my-app>
</div>
```

Comment: @scrappedcola OK! Thanks

Comment: @scrappedcola Done.